# inserção de tabela dentro de outra tabela

Tags: sql

é possível inserir um tipo de tabela dentro de outra?
Exemplo: tenho a tabela LIVRO e, dentro dela, quero criar uma coluna do tipo AUTOR (fazendo referencia à tabela AUTOR propriamente dita).

Comment: Não poderia ser uma chave estrangeira (ID_AUTOR) por exemplo que faria referencia a Chave primária da tabela AUTOR?

Comment: Seguindo a orientação do @ClaytonTosatti, leia https://www.devmedia.com.br/sql-aprenda-a-utilizar-a-chave-primaria-e-a-chave-estrangeira/37636

Comment: é que eu to montando as queries a partir do codigo java que eu fiz.
no meu codigo, dentro da classe livro, tem um atributo do tipo autor e queria fazer isso pro sql também.
Nao sei se ficou claro a minha questao..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível sim!
[Aqui](http://www.guj.com.br/t/resolvido-como-inserir-uma-tabela-na-outra-com-o-insert/285801/4) vai te dar uma noção melhor, mas já adiantando:

```
INSERT INTO tabelaA SELECT * FROM tabelaB
```

Comment: mas aí que tá a dúvida: ainda estou fazendo os CREATE's, consigo fazer isso na hora de criar a tabela? Ou é melhor criar a tabela e depois fazer um update inserindo esse campo?

Comment: Cria e faz o update :)

Comment: seria assim: ALTER TABLE livro ADD autor autor ?